# AWS API Gateway will I be charged for the request excess the throttling limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

For those requests excess the limit and get the response: 429 too many requests, will those requests still charge me?
In this question,t he throttling limit is the limit from the API gateway itself,  no other limit.

Comment: Related: https://repost.aws/questions/QUm1jSF1ieSQ25Ol1RzFLysA/does-aws-charge-for-throttled-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If you reached the limit for your usage plan and the API Gateway throttles you, there would be no additional costs. Although, this kind of throttling may not be as accurate as you would expect, see this question: [AWS API Gateway Throttling not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141984/aws-api-gateway-throttling-not-working-as-expected).

If your backend integration throws a `429` (for example, you reached some kind of Lambda limit), than your request will be charged on the API Gateway.